# C# windows application button in a grid view control

Tags: c#

I want to execute some code when a button in grid view control in my application is cliked.

Here I am assigning `datasource` property of grid view control at run time and i want to add a `button` control at the end of each row.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , be specific as to what u need to do with the button. Here we can only assume that u may need to add an Action Column  in your gridview and would need it for Deletion/Edit of that particular row. Here's what u can do to add an extra column in your grid view in asp:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                             <ItemTemplate>
                                                <div style="width: 40px; text-align: center">
                                                    <a href="pagetonavigate.aspx?QueryString=<%# Eval("QueryString")%>">
                                                        <img style="border: none; width: 20px; height: 20px" src="images/edit_pencil.png"
                                                            alt="Edit" title="Edit" />
                                                </div>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: i assumed u needed the control in the asp.net grid. Please be discriptive in your questions